# How to handle primary key in Mongodb if conflict Occurs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to copy selected record from Source database to destination database

This is accomplished by Below Code :

```
 //AspnetId For LoginUser
                var UserInfoDataList = searchUserInfo.AsQueryable();
                string AspNetId = "";
                foreach (var item in UserInfoDataList.ToList())
                {
                    AspNetId = item.AspNetId;
                }
                var AspnetIdQuery = Query.EQ("_id",ObjectId.Parse(AspNetId));
                var SerachAspNetUser = AspNetUserCollection.Find(AspnetIdQuery).ToList();
                var InsertAspNetUsercollection = destinationDatabase.GetCollection<ApplicationUser>("AspNetUsers");
                InsertAspNetUsercollection.InsertBatch(SerachAspNetUser, WriteConcern.Acknowledged);
```

Now when i update source database and again sync it to Target Database,How i will detect primary key conflict so that i can use some kind of condition there or update only the changed part of the record.

Comment: I think you  have an issue in  your code in fact   '}' is not in the right place because you will insert  always the last userId

Comment: @BRAHIMKamel in this table i have only one Entry so it will be inserted as this is login table for a user... now i am going to change username so my primary key will conflict .. now what to do?

Comment: so you have to do searchUserInfo.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault() and you have to update your driver to  2.0

Answer (score 0):

First of all try to update your c# driver to 2.0  than you can use [`ReplaceOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/) and `upsert = true` which will check if no document match the filter a new one will be inserted

After you can Try this

```
var UserInfoData = searchUserInfo.AsQueryable().FirstOrDefault;

  string  AspNetId = UserInfoData.AspNetId;                 

 var SerachAspNetUser = AspNetUserCollection.AsQueryable().SingleOrDefault(u=>u._id==AspNetId);
var InsertAspNetUsercollection = destinationDatabase.GetCollection<ApplicationUser>("AspNetUsers");
                        InsertAspNetUsercollection.ReplaceOne(Builders<yourModel>.Eq(u=>u._id,AspNetId),UserInfoData ,new UpdateOptions {IsUpsert = true} );
```

Comment: I have some issues due to which i am not able to update my c# driver. Issue is with aspnet.identity for user management